# Htaccess Page redirection from a specific domain leads to 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS'

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Following is my code for redirection.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.alternativedomain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^alternativedomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.primarydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works well. redirection happens but the resulting page shows the error as given below:

This page isn’t working [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Please help me!!

thanks.

Comment: It might help here if you write what is your expected result. What do you want to achieve? You can then search for other questions. I assume you want to redirect other domains to your canonical domain. There are already several questions here requesting to do this.

Comment: It would also help if you wrote what redirects where in your example. Give example URL, actual redirect results and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.domain.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(|/)$ https://www.test.domain.com/test-domain/stest-domain/ [R=301,L]

Thanks

Comment: Given your question, this does not really make sense. In your question you want to redirect from other domains to www.primarydomain.com. Here, you redirect to the same domain. If you find a solution to your own question it might be nice to add an explanation what was the problem and how this fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

First of, with provided information there is real help possible without further informations.

Somewhere there are additional redirects happening. You have to check all places, following the white rabbit from the start.

Are both domains(with subdomains) pointing to the exact same docroot ? (and so using the same .htaccess ) ? If yes, without full .htaccess no one can help you. Check all rewrite rules in there.

1. Check all redirects for .htaccess rewrite rules where (|www).alternativedomain.com points to
2. Check all redirects for .htaccess where [www.primarydomain.com](http://www.primarydomain.com) points to
3. Check for shortcut redirects in Typo3 / DomainRecord Redirects (Do not know if new SiteConfig Think has similar ones) (because it was asked in Typo3 slack - mainly check your code, system, html also if it is not Typo3)
4. Check redirect extension redirects (v9 +) if used

So that is in General what you can check. Maybe try to visualize first which redirects are happening. If the domains are accessible for all / public Internet, you can use online redirect checker to get ALL redirects, and eventually gaining more information WHO is redirecting, for ex. http://www.redirect-checker.org/

Producing something like that:

```
>>> http://www.primarydomain.com

> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Date:   Thu, 27 Aug 2020 14:41:52 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d3650e5fe5cc4330ddf77efb41010795a1598539311; expires=Sat, 26-Sep-20 14:41:51 GMT; path=/; domain=.primarydomain.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Expires:    Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control:  no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Location:   https://primarydomain.com/
X-Endurance-Cache-Level:    2
CF-Cache-Status:    DYNAMIC
cf-request-id:  04d1f73fc80000084b58a59200000001
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 5c968e45fb20084b-CDG




>>> https://primarydomain.com/

> --------------------------------------------
> 200 OK
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 200 OK
Code:   200
Date:   Thu, 27 Aug 2020 14:41:54 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d5a1fcf93be3a0b73390c14fc9bacbe601598539312; expires=Sat, 26-Sep-20 14:41:52 GMT; path=/; domain=.primarydomain.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Link:   <https://primarydomain.com/index.php/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/", <https://primarydomain.com/>; rel=shortlink
Cache-Control:  max-age=600
Expires:    Thu, 27 Aug 2020 14:51:53 GMT
Vary:   Accept-Encoding
X-Endurance-Cache-Level:    2
CF-Cache-Status:    DYNAMIC
cf-request-id:  04d1f74733000008af6ca0a200000001
Expect-CT:  max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 5c968e51dcef08af-CDG
```

This do not cover eventually javascript / meta tag redirects, but can still be used to get to THAT point. And so on.

Otherwise, if you can narrow it down to the .htaccess (one or eventually both for both domains), and you cannot see it yourself why it is redirected back, activating .htaccess RewriteRule logs could be a utillity to find it. If you are able to activate it (apache vhost, not htaccess - sadly).

Otherwise you can try online htaccess rule checker. There you can provide/paste your .htaccess file, and the "calling" url. And it will tell you what rules are matching, which not .. and what the result ist.

Sadly, these are not supporting all that is possible in .htaccess.

For example: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

> Note: Provided links are just examples, google for your own. Have no "love that" -- if i need, i google for checker, do not have bookmarked them. Sometimes is the one or other ;)

Until now, these steps in generell helped me in the past to find redirect missmatches/failures.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. I have checked my Htaccess file This is the only redirection I have given. As by http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php, I can see 19 redirections are happening that's why this. I don't know where all these came

Comment: So you have 19 redirects. What you have to do:

Start with the first redirect, and doing the same steps:

- What is called. Where is it, and which triggers there the redirect.

But sorry. Without that trace no one can tell you what happens.
Eventually providing that "redirect" output of the 19 redirects, someone can you give a fruther hint which or where to check.

Comment: CHECK it. "Don't know why my car is not running". Check iif it has fuel, or other issues. But just sitting there and waiting that it works - will keep you wait forever, in special if it just missing fuel,

Comment: All of the 19 redirects are just the same . When I remove the redirection code, 19 of them was disappeared. Is something wrong with the redirection code I mentioned above??

Comment: If this is the only rule in the .htacces, it should work .. for it self. As long as tsting it with nline .htaccess rule checker.

Please provide the full redirect chain / log from the redirect checker. Or give the "real" domain so we can see it ourself.

The "meta data" rule in your post itself works. So the problem is not that rule itself, it is something other.

Check your server logs, activate rewrite mod log and so on. There must be something, but with the provided information we can only guess. Mostyl things are noted what and how to check in the anser.